# Subscription runs in ngOnInit function after Component is destroyed and Revisited

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, behaviorsubject

I am running into a very strange situation with Angular Components and rxjs Subscriptions.

I have the following `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` functions

```
ngOnInit() {
    zip(this.service.getMessage, this.service.getType)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$))
      .subscribe(data => {
        const notification = new Notification(data[0], data[1]);
        this.notifications.push(notification);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.componentDestroyed$.next(true);
    this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
}
```

The subscription is active after setting the values with a Source and Subject paradigm in a service file that looks like this:

```
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
private message = this.messageSource.asObservable();
private typeSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(-1);
private type = this.typeSource.asObservable();

...
...

set setMessage(message: string) {
  this.messageSource.next(message);
}

set setType(type: number) {
  this.typeSource.next(type);
}
```

The initial subscription works fine, as expected. However, navigating away from the Component and navigating back to the same Component runs the `zip` subscription again in `ngOnInit`, even after the component was destroyed when navigating away. How to prevent this from happening? I have also tried defining a subscription variable and calling `unsubscribe`. I am stumped.

Comment: When you navigate back to the component the component is initialized from the ground up and `ngOnInit` is run _again_. So naturally the subscription is initiated once more.

Comment: Hey @MichaelD, thanks. That is right. However, the subscription in `ngOnInit` contains the previous values that were emitted before the component was destroyed. Shouldn't those values be empty if I am not emitting any values when navigating back?

Comment: The `BehaviorSubject` holds the current value (even if it's emitted before the component is destroyed) and emits it immediately upon subscription. The `BehaviorSubject`s in the service have no context if the component is created or destroyed, they edit immediately upon subscription. If you want the observables to emit only _after_ it's pushed a new value, you could use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: @MichaelD I spent hrs tracking this, `BehaviorSubject` has always worked for my cases except this time. I have always used it and never knew that subtle distinction between `BehaviorSubject` and `Subject`. Thank you! I will accept your solution, if you take the time to post it.

Comment: You're welcome :). I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand upon my comment, RxJS [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject)s hold the current value pushed to it and emit it immediately upon subscription. It also allows you to use the unique [`getValue()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject#getvalue-) function (or [`value`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L19) getter) on `BehaviorSubject` that allows you to synchronously retrieve the current value held by it. Although usage of this getter is usually frowned upon.

So in your case, when you're routing back to the component, the subscription emits the previous held value by both the observables. Instead you could use RxJS [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject) that do *not* hold values and emit only after a value is pushed to it.

```js
private messageSource = new Subject<string>();
private message = this.messageSource.asObservable();
private typeSource = new Subject<number>();
private type = this.typeSource.asObservable();
...
```

---

I'd also recommend you to see RxJS [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject). It's a more flexible multicast observable. It takes in the number of notifications to be buffered and emits them immediately upon new subscriptions.

So a `ReplaySubject(1)` (buffer 1) is similar to `BehaviorSubject` except it doesn't need a default value. So if you were to subscribe to it when nothing has been pushed into it yet, it won't emit.

<sup>It doesn't help you with the current issue, but might be helpful where you wish to have the behavior of `BehaviorSubject` but don't wish to deal with an unnecessary default value.</sup>